Is there any way to set up google ads just for testing purpose?
I have the Shopify site and recently updated the checkout logic since Shopify update the implementation and I want to test if the google ads works and show the conversion. I don't mind paying a few dollars but want to know there is a easy way to set up with existing google account or new account.
